# Incompatible Types PAnsiChar and PWideChar since StrAlloc returns PWideChar with StrAlloc

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I know this can be simple but at times Unicode issues bother me lot with too much of considerations.

I have this code:

```
pcBuffer := StrAlloc(Stream.Size + 1) where pcBuffer is defined as PWideChar
```

The component wants `pcBuffer as PAnsiChar` now, so If I do so, I get the error for

> StrAlloc- Incompatible Types PAnsiChar and PWideChar

since StrAlloc returns PWideChar

How do I solve this?

Can I simply type cast to `PAnsiChar or alloacate` it in Unicode way or through GetMem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Delphi XE, the `SysUtils` unit defines the following functions:

```
function AnsiStrAlloc(Size: Cardinal): PAnsiChar;
function WideStrAlloc(Size: Cardinal): PWideChar;
function StrAlloc(Size: Cardinal): PChar;
```

You should be calling `AnsiStrAlloc` to allocate a `PAnsiChar`. This receives a `Size` measured in characters. You must account for the null-terminator.

```
var
  pcBuffer: PAnsiChar;
....
pcBuffer := AnsiStrAlloc(Stream.Size + 1);
```

However, these functions should be considered deprecated. They are documented as such in the later versions of Delphi. Instead you should probably use `AnsiString` and so let the compiler manage lifetime and memory allocation.

```
var
  str: AnsiString;
  pcBuffer: PAnsiChar;
....
SetLength(str, Stream.Size);
pcBuffer := PAnsiChar(str);
```

The lifetime of the buffer is managed by the compiler as is the case for any Delphi string variable.

It's quite possible that the code above is not the best way to solve your actual problem. Without seeing more details it's hard to say for sure what the best solution is. The only thing that I'm reasonably confident about is that `StrAlloc` and friends are not the way forward.

Comment: @Shanand Dispose a string by letting it leave scope, or by setting it to '' or by calling Finalize etc. Obviously use whatever functions you choose to, even deprecated ones if you choose. It's odd that you accept an answer that appears to be wrong, albeit in a matter of detail, and mention code that won't compile in XE, the tagged version. You aren't using XE are you? Your comment is very confusing. It's frustrating to put effort in to answering and find that the question got crucial details wrong. I'm sure Remy will fix the code in his answer in due course.

Comment: David: Apologies.. incorrectly ticked the wrong answer.. but I at least got the problem narrowed down to use - AnsiStrings.AnsiStrAlloc(Stream.Size + 1) as suggested by remy; which was then corrected by you. Since you commented under Remy's I ticked to that. Rather I was happy with your reply to his comment which worked for me. My question I think was pretty clear where U have rightly replied, Thanks for your help! Will surely need your assistance ahead in future.

Comment: Existing code in D2007, need to rewrite that line in XE6 (that was the question). Anyways- Its resolved and I am on with other issues. Thanks David & Remy

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `StrAlloc()` from the `SysUtils` unit, which allocates a `PWideChar`.

To allocate a `PAnsiChar` instead, call the `StrAlloc()` from the `AnsiStrings` unit:

```
uses
  ..., AnsiStrings;

pcBuffer := AnsiStrings.StrAlloc(Stream.Size + 1);
```

Comment: So far as I can tell, there has never been anything named `AnsiStrings.StrAlloc`. You are probably thinking of `AnsiStrings.AnsiStrAlloc`. But the question is tagged XE in which case not even `AnsiStrings.AnsiStrAlloc` exists. In XE the function is `SysUtils.AnsiStrAlloc`.